# The conjugation action $\mathbb{H}^*\times \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ restricted to unit-quaternions yields an orthogonal representation

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, covering-spaces, quaternions, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the action $\mathbb{H}^*\times\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}, (h,h')\mapsto hh'h^{-1}$.
Show that it preserves the orthogonal-decomposition $\mathbb{R}\bigoplus $Im$\mathbb{H}$, and therefore when restricted to unit quaternions $S^{3} = \{h \in \mathbb{H} | \overline{h}h = 1\}$ yields an orthogonal representation
\[S^3 \xrightarrow{\phi}\text{SO(Im}\mathbb{H})\cong SO(3)\]
with kernel $\{\pm 1\}$. Conclude that $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism and hence a covering map.

My ideas so far:
$S^3$ has dimension $3$ as well as $SO(3)$  since dim $SO(n) = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}$.
Therefore by Prop.$4.8$ in Lee it suffices to show that $\phi$ is either a submersion or an immersion. Since $S^3$ and $SO$(Im($\mathbb{H})$ are embedded submanifolds, ($SO$(Im($\mathbb{H})$ is a linear subspace) the map $\phi$ should at least be smooth.
But I don't quite understand why the action preserves the orthogonal decomposition.
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Use the fact that the norm is multiplicative, that is $| ab| = |a||b|$, for quaternions. It follows that $|h^{-1}|=|h|^{-1}1$ and therefore for any $x$, $|h\cdot x| = |hxh^{-1}|=|h||x||h^{-1}| = |x|$. The action of $\Bbb H ^*$ preserves the norm, so that it is orthogonal. Now, since the action stabilizes $\Bbb R$ (since real numbers commute with quaternions), it stabilizes its orthogonal complement $\Bbb R^{\perp} = \mathrm{Im} \Bbb H$.

Comment: $SO(Im(\mathbb H))$ refers to the special orthogonal group, so this is not a linear subspace and smoothness does need an argument. However, you can compute the map $S^3\to SO(Im(\mathbb H))$ explicitly in terms of matrices, so that smoothness is not difficult to prove. (This relies to the fact that $SO(3)$ is an embedded submanifold in the space of $3\times 3$-matrices.)

Comment: Thank you @Didier I understood your points. That means the action acts "seperately" on the real and the imaginary part right ? And we had a representation of $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{R}\cdot SU(2)$ in the lecture. I used that to write h = \begin{pmatrix}
u & -\overline{v}\\
v & \overline{u}
\end{pmatrix} And in the same way h^-{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
\overline{u} & \overline{v}\\
-v & u  \end{pmatrix} (Since |h| = 1). I then carried out the matrix-product of $hh'h^{-1}$ explicitly. But I dont know what to do with it now. I don't see why the result should be in $SO(Im(\mathbb(H))$.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Cap.\                                                                                      
Just to check if my understanding is correct:  $SO(Im(\mathbb{H}))$ is the set of matrices $h = aE+bI+cJ+dK$ such that $a=0$ and $h^{T}\cdot h = E$ ?

Comment: No, you are looking at linear maps $Im(\mathbb H)\to Im(\mathbb H)$, so choosing a basis of $Im(\mathbb H)$ you can write them as $3\times 3$-matrices. You also need an inner product on $Im(\mathbb H)$ and in the matrix representation with respect to an orthonormal basis, $SO(Im(\mathbb H))$ are the matrices that satisfy $AA^t=I$.

Comment: Hey @AndreasCap thank you for your patience.  I have seen both the representation of $\mathbb{H}$ as $\mathbb{R} \cdot SO(2)$ and as 4x4 matrices. But I don't know how one could reduce this to a rep. of $Im(\mathbb{H})$ as 3x3-matrices. I have looked it up and we haven't done that in the lecture either. I also tried this today and it didn't work out :/ If you happen to have any resource/link on that that you could send. That would really make my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick exercise-review of how to write linear operators as matrices with respect to bases. Consider the vector space of real-coefficient polynomials with degree $\le 2$. The derivative $D$ is a linear operator. If we pick the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, we may apply $D$ to the basis elements and express the results as linear combinations:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
D1 & = & 0(1) & + & 0(x) & + & 0(x^2) \\
Dx & = & 1(1) & + & 0(x) & + & 0(x^2) \\
Dx^2 & = & 0(1) & + & 2(x) & + & 0(x^2)
\end{array}$$

Therefore we can represent $D$ by the $3\times3$ matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

So for example, if you think of $1,x,x^2$ as $e_1,e_2,e_3$ respectively, then $De_1=0$, $De_2=e_1$, $De_3=2e_2$.

---

Pick the basis $\{\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$ for $\mathrm{Im}\,\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{R}^3$.

To turn a unit quaternion $a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$ into a $3\times3$ matrix, check how conjugating by it affects the basis vectors. For example, if we let $p=\mathbf{i}$ then we can compute

$$\begin{array}{lcr}
\mathbf{iii}^{-1} & = & \mathbf{i} \\
\mathbf{iji}^{-1} & = & -\mathbf{j} \\
\mathbf{iki}^{-1} & = & -\mathbf{k}
\end{array}$$

and therefore $\mathbf{i}\in S^3$ corresponds to the matrix

$$ \mathbf{i}\longleftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} .$$

Can you do the same for $p=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$? Note the reciprocal of a unit quaternion is its quaternion conjugate so there's no need for rational functions. You should then be able to define $S^3\to SO(3)$ as an explicit function.

Comment: Thank you for your help @runway. I have found in the same way that $p = a + b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
a+b & 0 & 0\\
-c & a-b+c & -c\\ 
-d& -d & d-b+a                                                                                                             
 \end{bmatrix}. $ This map is clearly smooth. Further it is linear and injective since only for the zero-quaternion all entries vanish. But then by the isomorphism theorem, the image should be a subgroup. And then since $dimS^3 = dimSO(3) = 3, \:\varphi$ should be an isomorphism.I hope that is correct.

Comment: I just fail to see why this is a matrix in SO(3). I calculated $A^{T}A$ and the determinant and they were pretty ugly

Comment: @PaulJoh Your matrix is wrong. Let's try just one column of the matrix. What do you get for the conjugate $p{\bf i}p^{-1}$, or more explicitly, $(a+b{\bf i}+c{\bf j}+d{\bf k})\,{\bf i}\, (a-b{\bf i}-c{\bf j}-d{\bf k})\,$?

Comment: Okay I got                                                                                         
\begin{pmatrix}
(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2) & (2bc-2ad) & (2ac+2bd)\\
(2ad+2bc) & (a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2) & (2cd-2ab)\\                 
(2bd-2ac) & (2ab+2cd) & (a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)
\end{pmatrix}  At least when I multiply it with its transpose I get a diagonal matrix with identical diagonal entries...

Comment: @PaulJoh For $a+b{\bf i}+c{\bf j}+d{\bf k}$ to be a unit quaternion, its norm must be $1$, so $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$, which should make those diagonal entries $1$. :-)

Comment: Yeah thanks I just miscalculated alot. But now after some pretty lengthy calculations I get the correct result. Thanks to everyone who helped with this exercise !