# Determine the conjugacy-classes in the unit-quaternions $S^3$

Tags: lie-groups, compactness, group-actions, quaternions, submanifold

The question is already in the heading. Determine all conjugacy-classes of the unit-quaternions $S^3=\{h \in \mathbb{H} | \: \bar{h}\cdot h = 1\}$.

My only idea to tackle this question would be:
Since $S^3$ is compact and the action (conjugation) is smooth, the conjugacy classes should be compact embedded submfs.

Another idea would be to somehow use the representation here: [The conjugation action $\mathbb{H}^*\times \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ restricted to unit-quaternions yields an orthogonal representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4397904/1032545)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember all unit quaternions have polar forms $e^{\theta\mathbf{u}}$ where $\theta$ is a convex angle (i.e. $0\le\theta\le\pi$) and $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector (so, a sqrt of $-1$), and Euler's formula says $e^{\theta\mathbf{u}}=\cos\theta+\sin\theta\,\mathbf{u}$. Conjugating by $e^{\theta\mathbf{u}}$ has no effect on reals but has the effect of rotating vectors by $2\theta$ around the $\mathbf{u}$-axis. Any vector of a given size can be rotated to any other vector of the same size.

Thus, for each $0\le\theta\le\pi$ there is a conjugacy class of all $e^{\theta\mathbf{v}}$ with $\mathbf{v}\in S^2$. For $\theta=0,\pi$ these are singletons $\{+1\},\{-1\}$ respectively but otherwise they are two-spheres within $S^3$.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am not familiar with polar forms but I am going to read up on it. If there was any other solution without polar forms that would be great.

Comment: @PaulJoh Morally, you should understand polar forms, because any other kind proof would completely blind to what's going on. Polar form works the same for quaternions as it does for complex numbers. And also look up how conjugating 3D vectors (aka pure imaginary quaternions) by unit quaternions yields 3D rotations. These are very important to understanding quaternions in general and solving all sorts of problems with them, not just solving this one problem!